# Vue links are formatted weirdly

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am new to Vue js, Inertia and Laravel.

But I have gotten stuck and cannot figure out what the problem is even though I try searching google and looking at videos.

I have this code

```
    <div v-for="(seed, index) in seeds" :key="index">
       Id {{ seed.id }} 
       <inertia-link :href="'/fert/' + '{{ seed.id }}'">
         Go to seed
       </inertia-link>
    </div>
```

And The first `{{ seed.id }}` outside of the links looks great, it shows the actual id.
However then `{{ seed.id }}` within the link formats, so the link shows this:

```
Id 1<a href="/fert/%7B%20seed.id%20%7D">Go to seed</a>
```

Why is it formatting inside the link but not outside? and how to I fix it?

Thanks in advance, and yes I am very noob. sorry

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use curly braces in attribute's value.
Using :[attribute-name] already tells Vue that you gonna use some JS expressions in value

```
:href="'/fert/' + seed.id"
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use curly braces within the link. A nicer way to concatenate vars with text is to use template literal ES6 with backticks

```
<inertia-link :href="`/fert/${seed.id}`">Go to seed</inertia-link>
```